# Build android studio signed apk with release build type

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-build-type

My android project is configured to have 2 build types: `Debug` and `Release`. I'm using android studio 3.1.4.

I did define the key store and other key details for my `Release` build type however clicking `Build --> Build APK(s)` in android studio will only build `Debug` version. I want to know are there any methods that `Build APK(s)` option also build the `Release`version too?

P.S.: I know that I can use terminal and run `gradlew assembleRelease` to build Release version.

Comment: You simply need to change `Build Variant` opening the bottom-left panel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick `Build Variants` tab at the bottom-left panel and choose a release type:

[image]

P.S. Don't forget to give a credit to the @[MatPag's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795012/build-android-studio-signed-apk-with-release-build-type#comment92510709_52795012).